# What's the difference between quasi-concavity and concavity?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

1. What's the intuitive difference between quasi-concavity and concavity?
2. Can you give an example of a quasi-concave function that is not concave?

Comment: Suppose $f$ is $C^1(\mathbb{R})$.  A nice additional way of viewing the difference (and the reason it's cared about in economics, say) is that $f'$ is monotone decreasing if $f$ is concave, and is single crossing for the zero line if $f$ is quasi-concave (the importance lying in the ubiquitousness of first-order conditions).  So in terms of getting a unique (or at least convex) set of solutions to the FOC, concavity is 'global', whereas quasi-concavity is only 'local'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

A function with this graph is quasiconcave, but not concave. It can be proved that a function $f$ is quasiconcave if and only there exists $x_0$ s.t. $f$ is nondecreasing for $x<x_0$ while $f$ is nonincreasing for $x>x_0$. I don't write precisely about a domain. It should be interval on a real line. Of course, quasiconcavity could be also defined on a plane or on any linear space.

Another characterization of quasiconcavity: $f:D\to\Bbb R$ (where $D$ is a convex subset of a linear space) is quasiconcave iff
$$
f\bigl(tx+(1-t)y\bigr)\ge \min\{f(x),f(y)\}
$$
for any $x,y\in D$, $t\in[0,1]$.

This graph consists of two convex pieces. Nevertheless, the whole function is quasiconcave.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! If I understand quasi-concavity correctly, then every stricty increasing function must be quasi-concave, right?

Comment: And also quasi-convex. :) Functions $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ which are both quasiconcave and quasiconvex are precisely monotonic functions. In higher dimensions they are called quasi-monotonic.

Comment: Perfect, :) Thanks!

Comment: Is there an example of an f(x,y) which is convex but also quasi concave?

Comment: @Pgupta Any monotone convex function works for the example. Observe that any convex function is quasiconvex. So, in particular, we look for a function which is both quasiconvex and quasiconcave. In the case of one-dimensional domain, this is a monotone function (see my previous comments).

Comment: Thanks, so $e^{x+y}$ works here. Could you provide any other examples?

Comment: Yes, it is. Indeed, the super-level sets are half-planes, which are obviously convex. The function in question is now both quasiconvex and quasiconcave. As a function of multiple variable it is then quasimonotone.

Answer (score 4):

1. A function $f(x)$ is said to be *quasi-concave* if its domain and all its $\alpha$-superlevel sets defined as

$$\mathcal{S}_\alpha \triangleq\{x|x\in dom f, f(x)\geq\alpha\}$$

are convex for every $\alpha$.
   Another representation of quasi-concave functions: $f(x)$ is called quasi-
   concave if and only if

$$f(\theta x+(1-\theta)y) \geq \min\{f(x),f(y)\}$$

for all $x,y \in dom f$ and $\theta\in[0,1]$.

2. A function $f(x)$ is said to be *concave* if the two conditions below satisfied:

   (i) $dom f$ is convex.

   (ii) For all $x,y\in dom f$ and $\theta\in[0,1],$

$$f(\theta x+(1-\theta)y) \geq \theta f(x) + (1-\theta)f(y)$$

In fact, this implies that if a function is convcave then that's also quasi-concave but not necessarily the converse is true.

3. For example $f(\mathbf{X}) = \text{rank}(\mathbf{X})$ is a quasi-concave on $\mathbb{S}^n_{+}$.
4. Ceiling function $f(x)= \lceil x \rceil$ is a quasi-concave function (also, it is quasi-convex which is called quasi-linear).

---

References for more info.:

1. Convex Optimization for Signal Processing and Communications, by Chong-Yung Chi.
2. Convex Optimization by Stephen Boyd.

Comment: how is 2. an answer to OP's second question ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon: you can refer to each reference above. Here, you can multiply both sides by negative sign and you will find the sublevel sets associated with the quasi-convex functions.