# How to tell if from a graph if the function is quasiconvex or quasiconcave?

Tags: statistics, functions

I'm struggling with home assignment.
How to tell just by looking at the graph, if the function is quasiconcave or quasiconvex?

[graphs here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXF1i.png)

Any help is huugely appreciated.

Comment: In 1D quasiconvexity/concavity is equivalent to unimodality (single change between growth and decrease), see [What's the difference between quasi-concavity and concavity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2500035/152568). In contour plots you just have to check the definition directly, whether the insides/outsides of the contours are convex.

Comment: Do you understand the relationship between quasiconvexity and the epigraph of the function?