# Gradient-based methods on quasi-convex problems?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

In the book I am currently reading, it says

> Gradient-based methods are useful for one global optimum and no
> additional local optima: (quasi-)concave for maximums, (quasi-)convex for
> minimums.

It is clear to me why concave and convex functions work, as it implies that there is only one maximum/minimum and if it is continuous the gradient-based method will probably work well.

However I am struggling with the quasi-convex/quasi-concave functions. But look at the simple example in [What's the difference between quasi-concavity and concavity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2500035/whats-the-difference-between-quasi-concavity-and-concavity). We will struggle when applying the gradient-based method, right?

So I assume the quote above is not sufficient. Can I use gradient-based methods on quasi-concave/convex functions and when should I better be careful?